# android Java шифрование строки публичный плючомRSA

Tags: java, android, криптография, rsa

у меня стандартная задача:

1. получить с сервера публичный ключ RSA в Android-приложение (кодирую его
   при передаче в Base64)
2. Зашифровать введенный пароль и передать его на
       сервер (кодирую при передаче в Base64)

Ключи генерятся на сервере библиотекой phpseclib/phpseclib  - на самом сервере кодирование-декодирование работает.
Проверял доставку, посылал уже зашифрованный пароль на клиента и с клиента отправлял на сервер, все работает и расшифровывается.

Но в приложение это не работает.

Вот функции кодирования в приложениии:

```
String key = jobj.optString("public_key","");
byte[] data = Base64.decode(key, Base64.NO_WRAP);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");

PublicKey pubKey = Tools.getPublicKeyFromPemFormat(text,false);
String passEncode = Tools.encrypt2(pass,  pubKey ) ;
Log.e("passEncode",passEncode);


  public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromPemFormat(String PEMString,
                                                      boolean isFilePath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {

        BufferedReader pemReader = null;
        if (isFilePath) {
            pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(PEMString)));
        } else {
            pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(PEMString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        }
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----") != -1) {
                while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.indexOf("-----END PUBLIC KEY") != -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    content.append(line.trim());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (line == null) {
            throw new IOException("PUBLIC KEY" + " not found");
        }
        Log.i("PUBLIC KEY: ", "PEM content = : " + content.toString());

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(content.toString(), Base64.NO_WRAP)));

    }

public static String encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Если здесь ошибка?

Кодируя этими функциями получаю  результат -  строка которая потом не декодируется с правильным приватным ключом.

Comment: Что значит не работает? Что значит не декодируется? Как декодируете?

Comment: (а ещё я подозрваю, что способ использования RSA здесь очень небезопасен, но точно не уверен, с RSA в андроиде не работал)

Comment: А вообще — зачем всё это нужно, чем HTTPS не угодил?

Comment: В данном случае сайт без сертификата(( поэтому так.  Не работает - значит что в итоге полученая строка не декодирется обратно.

Comment: Ещё раз: что значит не декодируется? Как декодируете?

Comment: Декодирую на стороне сервера той же библиотекой phpseclib/phpseclib. Собственно в ней же генерил ключи. У этой библиотек 28млн скачиваний, по этому вроде сомнений в ней нет. Но видимо скоро проверю и на другой библиотеке ее результат.

Comment: [Сертификаты SSL для сайтов в наше время стоят ровным счётом ничего.](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/free-ssl-from-letsencrypt/) Может всё-таки не изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Сертификат, это этап номер два. Это будет - вопрос когда?. И полностью согласен - это Велосипед.

Comment: При таком велосипеде сертификат вполне может выступать первым и единственным этапом

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо  andreymal ,
я нашел это, вернее вы подсказали.

Нужно было проставить в PHP по умолчанию

```
 $rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
```

И в финкции на java

изменить одну строку

```
 public static String encrypt2(String text, PublicKey key) {
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        try {
            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            // encrypt the plain text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

А то я уж подумал, что вообще не понимаю как это работает)). Спасибо.