# PHP алгоритм RSA в разных библиотеках

Tags: php, rsa

взял две библиотеки для шифрования в RSA:
phpseclib/phpseclib
liamylian/x-rsa

И сделал следующее:

1. протестировал что каждая шифрует и дешифрует своими ключами.
2. взял ключи из одной и передал их в другую - сработало.

Но, когда взял публичный ключ и зашифровал фразу в phpseclib/phpseclib, то приватным ключом в liamylian/x-rsa расшифровать фразу не смог.  Разве это правильно????, что алгоритм не уневерсален?

Comment: Возможно правильно, потому что никто никогда ни в коем случае не должен использовать сырой RSA, потому что это абсолютно небезопасно. Попробуйте почитать документацию по всем этим библиотекам и разобраться, в каких режимах и с какими паддингами они работают — возможно, причина проблем в их различиях. То же самое относится в [вашему предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855782)

Comment: Спасибо,  буду копать.

Comment: Великое спасибо))     Padding имел место быть. Оказалось, что по умолчанию в  первой библиотеке стоял ENCRYPTION_OAEP, а в другой OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING  )) Со второй библиотекой все равно "темная ситуация", но зато первая и openssl_public_encrypt - начали друг-друга понимать!!! Так что уже могу дальше двигаться, спасибо.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесено из комментариев:

> Возможно правильно, потому что никто никогда ни в коем случае не должен использовать сырой RSA, потому что это абсолютно небезопасно. Попробуйте почитать документацию по всем этим библиотекам и разобраться, в каких режимах и с какими паддингами они работают — возможно, причина проблем в их различиях.

Продолжение:

> Оказалось, что по умолчанию в первой библиотеке стоял ENCRYPTION_OAEP, а в другой OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING.